# How to get the Business Name via Payments REST API?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

On the [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) API Operation (NVP), there is a BUSINESS-Tag  (Buyer's business name).

How can I get this business name via [Payments REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/)?